# How to add and remove class from marker using gmaps4rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

**Below is my controller code for create new marker**

```
     @vnote_hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@vnotes) do |vnote, marker|

        marker.lat vnote["latitude"]
        marker.lng vnote["longitude"]
        marker.json({:trip_vnote_id => vnote["id"] })

        marker.picture({
         "url" => "images",
         "width" =>  SHOW_SMALL_THUMB_IMAGE_WIDTH,
         "height" => SHOW_SMALL_THUMB_IMAGE_HEIGHT})
     end
```

**in short, i want to do like differentiate click marker and un-click marker.**

[image]

Comment: I would like to add a class to the marker when clicking on it. I've searched the API but I can't find a solution. Do you have any leads?

Comment: which `class` are you talking about? a marker doesnt have any class

Comment: @apneadiving - without marker have any class, how can i change marker image on on_click_listner? Thanx for reply

Comment: basically you have to listen for click events on markers, then create a new one and drop the existing (`addMarker`, `removeMarker`)